# PHP Regular Expression special characters

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching, expression

I am facing difficulties to validate the below format. I want regular expression needs to be satisfied with the below condition.

```
$pattern = '/^\w[\w\s\.\%\-\(\)\[\]]*$/u';
$file_name = "(00)filename.jpg";
if(preg_match($pattern,$file_name)){
    echo "Pattern matched";
}else {
    echo "Pattern not matched";
}
```

I have tried several ways. But, the main problem is do not write the own pregmatch, instead need to modify the existing one which accepts the brackets().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this should match `(00)filename.jpg` and does not, because your regex requires the string to `^\w` start with a word-character. You can add optional parenthesized `\w+` to the start:

```
^(?:\(\w+\)|\w)[-\w\s.%()[\]]*$
```

Also need to put the hyphen `-` at the start or end inside the character class. Else it would express a range. Furthermore need to escape the closing `]` inside the character class.

[test at regex101](http://regex101.com/r/zQ8iA2)

---

But possibly, you just want to check:

- if there's at least one word-character in the string.
- the string consist only of `[-\w\s.%()[\]]`

If so, use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check for the  `\w`:

```
^(?=.*?\w)[-\w\s.%()[\]]+$
```

[test at regex101](http://regex101.com/r/gH6dH3)

Comment: the first regex accepts unbalanced parentheses in the prefix string (eg. `00)filename.jpg`). `^(\(\w+\)|\w+)[-\w\s.%()[\]]*$`rectifies that.

Comment: @collapsar modified it, thanks. could also use a conditional like that: `^(\()?\w+(?(1)\))`

Comment: Hi guys. Thanks for your solution. Finally i have made the preg match like  '/\(?\w+\)?[\w\s\.\%\-\(\)\[\]]*$/u';

Comment: Hey user3644871. It should be `^\(?\w+\)?[-\w\s.%()[\]]*$` then :]